# Efficient boolean reductions `any`, `all` for PySpark RDD?

Tags: apache-spark

PySpark supports common reductions like `sum`, `min`, `count`, ...  Does it support boolean reductions like `all` and `any`?

I can always `fold` over `or_` and `and_`  but this seems inefficient.

Answer (score 12):

this is very late, but `all` on a set of `boolean` values `z` is the same as `min(z) == True` and `any` is the same as `max(z) == True`

Comment: If you expanded this a bit, it would really add to this question...

Comment: Would spark be smart enough to return True the moment it encounters first True. I am afraid that for any it might scan through all the rows. On the other hand, I think that the boolean dtype of the column might be used and spark might know that there are oly 0s and 1s in the column

Answer (score 2):

No the underlying [Scala API](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.0.0/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD) doesn't have it so the Python one definitely won't.  I don't think they will add it either as it's very easy to define in terms of `filter`.

Yes using `fold` would be inefficient because it won't parallelelize. Do something like `.filter(!condition).take(1).isEmpty` to mean `.forall(condition)` and `.filter(condition).take(1).nonEmpty` to mean `.exists(condition)`

(General suggestion: the underlying Scala API is generally more flexible than Python API, suggest you move to it - it also makes debugging much easier as you have less layers to dig through.  Scala means Scalable Language - it's much better for scalable applications and more robust than dynamically typed languages)

Comment: Note that of Spark 1.3+ it is possible to do `filter(condition).isEmpty` as that internally calls `take(1)`